# Determining $f^{-1}(3)$ without knowing $f^{-1}(x)$ but given $f(1)=3$ and $f'(x)>0$.

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse

I have a continuous function $f(x)$ and I want to find $f^{-1}(3)$, but I can't find $f^{-1}$ directly. I know that $f(1)=3$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all x. Because the function is continuous and always increasing, does that mean that the function necessarily has an inverse and that there is only one value s.t. $f(x)=3$, therefore $f^{-1}(3)=1$?

Comment: Yes, to put it simply.